# Crash when calling glfwInit from my language

Tags: windows, llvm, glfw, llvm-ir

I've been developing my own language and wanted to try to open a window using GLFW. This is the llvm-ir that was generated when compiling.

```
; ModuleID = 'main'
source_filename = "main"

declare i32 @glfwInit()

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %0 = call i32 @glfwInit()
  ret i32 0
}
```

I then link it with the link.exe compiler using the following command.

```
link.exe output\output.o /LIBPATH:bin /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /ENTRY:main /OUT:output/a.exe kernel32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib user32.lib msvcrtd.lib libucrtd.lib lib/vendor/glfw/bin/glfw3_mt.lib
```

The windows lib files I got from the windows 10 SDK and the glfw lib is from the 3.3.8 prebuild windows binaries lib-vc2022. But when I run the application it crashes at the call to glfwInit.

This is the stacktrack I got when running in windbg.

```
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00007ff6`b5890000 00007ff6`b5904000   image00007ff6`b5890000
ModLoad: 00007ff9`ab200000 00007ff9`ab409000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`a9d20000 00007ff9`a9dde000   C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`a8730000 00007ff9`a8ab4000   C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`aa630000 00007ff9`aadf5000   C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`a8690000 00007ff9`a872d000   C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`a8f30000 00007ff9`a9041000   C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`a97f0000 00007ff9`a999d000   C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`a8b80000 00007ff9`a8ba6000   C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`a9140000 00007ff9`a916a000   C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`a8e10000 00007ff9`a8f2f000   C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
(31a4.3c30): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ff9`ab2dcf84 cc              int     3
0:000> kb
 # RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00 00007ff9`ab2e00a8 : 00007ff9`ab335700 000000bf`13a43000 000000bf`13a43000 00007ff9`ab3333d8 : ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30
01 00007ff9`ab2cd870 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x1bec
02 00007ff9`ab27ad43 : 00000000`00000000 00007ff9`ab200000 000000bf`13a44000 000000bf`13a43050 : ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x52af4
03 00007ff9`ab27ac6e : 000000bf`13cff5e0 00000000`00000000 000000bf`13cff5e0 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!LdrpInitializeInternal+0x6b
04 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
```

I've been scratching my head for quite some time but can't figure out the problem. I understand that it's not a lot of information to go on, but any pointers to where to start digging would be very appreciate!

Comment: Since you're on Windows, I'd recommend firing up a low-level debugger like x64dbg and see what's going wrong.